# Supporting extra quotes around Unicode is deprecated in traitlets 5.0

Tags: python, jupyter

Issue:

`Kernel died with exit code 1073741845`

1.

```
c:\anaconda\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\traitlets\ traitlets.py :2196: FutureWarning: Supporting extra quotes around Unicode is deprecated in traitlets 5.0. Use 'hmac-sha256' instead of '"hmac-sha256"' – or use CUnicode.
```

2. 

```
warn( c:\anaconda\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py:2151: FutureWarning: Supporting extra quotes around Bytes is deprecated in traitlets 5.0. Use '7aa5b615-129a-4e47-b483-0954be3b7001' instead of 'b"7aa5b615-129a-4e47-b483-0954be3b7001"'.
```

3. 

```
warn( Bad file descriptor (bundled\zeromq\src\epoll.cpp:100)
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve 1. & 2. using the following commend in vscode python terminal:

`python -m pip install traitlets==4.3.3 --force-reinstall` (may need to run two times and shows successfully install)

This will reinstall traitlets to the lower version.

To solve 3. using the following commend in vscode python terminal:

`python -m pip install pyzmq==19.0.2 --force-reinstall` (may need to run two times and shows successfully install)

This will reinstall pyzmq to the lower version.

Comment: The 1 & 2 fix still raises a traitlets 5.0 error despite saying tha traitlets 4.3.3 was successfully installed.